# SQL Select Separate Value into Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I'm looking for some guidance in figuring out how to separate the value of one cell into multiple columns. Unfortunately the issue with this task lies in how the data is put together in the database.

Right now, I have a query that produces a consolidated table of values. Here is that query (I trimmed it down a bit for brevity's sake):

```
SELECT 
T1.order_item_id,
T2.order_item_id,
T2.order_id,

max(CASE 
    WHEN T1.meta_key = 'Address' and T2.order_item_id = T1.order_item_id 
    THEN T1.meta_value 
    END) as 'User Address'

FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta T1 
    LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items T2 
    ON T1.order_item_id = T2.order_item_id 

GROUP BY 
T1.order_item_id,
```

And this is the table it produces:

```
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 | order_item_id     | User Address                    |
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
 | 101               | 123 Fake St. Denver, CO USA     |                      
 +-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Which was initially ideal, but now we need to separate that address so that the table looks like this:

```
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | order_item_id     | Address      | City   | State | Country |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | 101               | 123 Fake St. | Denver | CO    | USA     |                      
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And frankly, I'm not even sure if that's possible. I checked several solutions here, and it seems there's ways to do this using:

```
 SELECT 
       column_name,REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(column_name) ,' ' ,'.') ,1)) 
 AS address 1
```

But because of how the data is saved into the database, I'm not able to use this to separate the values.

Is there a way to do this using the max CASE statement?

Comment: The problem is what logical would you follow?, Because I see right now you have split by `.` another by `,` and the last is for space. If all your data has same paterr you can do something, but unless you have `New_York`  and `South_Carolina` split by space will broke things up.

Comment: I agree with @JuanCarlosOropeza unless you can describe the precise logic (i.e. parse everything before the period into column 1, everything before the comma into 2, then everything before the next space into 3, etc.) then you can't really do this. Since it's not a guarantee that your streets end in a full stop and your city ends in a comma... and that you have no spaces in the data... You will need a human involved. But at least you learned a good lesson in db design!

Comment: If you are familiar with WooCommerce data storing process then you can get the State, City, country from `_billing_state`, `_billing_city` and `_billing_country` respectively `wp_postmeta.meta_key`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Is the value required to have a ',' or '.' in it to be able to be parsed? Right now the address is actually a bit of a mish mash, here's an actual example of how the data is stored: 123Fake St Denver,CO 80227.

Comment: @RaunakGupta - I have that also listed. The issue lies in how the client has their booking system setup. They're using gravity forms add on to collect data from the form. That data gets put under the woocommerce_order_itemmeta. Now the data under the gravity forms table has the address separated, but woocommerce consolidates the data combining the address, state, city and zip.

Comment: @gffwebdev I work with that kind of data everyday. There isnt an easy way fix a single address field without human intervention. When we got that kind of data from customers we have a team just to fix that.  Of course we have some tools to help to separate those field, but the final decision is made by a person. My suggestion fix the problem on the input with separated fields for Street, State, Country, etc.

Comment: @JacobH It's definitely a learning experience!

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'll look into that, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool from googlemaps called [reverse address lookup](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Where you send a string and he return possible locations. But you have to pay for each search.

Once you have a `latitud, longitud` you can drill down your layers for each field Country, State, Street